# Django - Abstract Base Class Model Breaking syncdb

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this in my models.py:

```
class AuditableTable(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related1")
        last_updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related1")

class Company(AuditableTable): pass
```

I believe I am following the [instructions related to abstract models mentioned here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name).

However I'm getting this error when I run manage.py syncdb:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
ItemLocator.company: Accessor for field 'created_by' clashes with related field 'User.itemlocator_company_related1'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'created_by'.                                                                                       
ItemLocator.company: Reverse query name for field 'created_by' clashes with related field 'User.itemlocator_company_related1'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'created_by'.                                                                             
ItemLocator.company: Accessor for field 'last_updated_by' clashes with related field 'User.itemlocator_company_related1'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'last_updated_by'.                                                                             
ItemLocator.company: Reverse query name for field 'last_updated_by' clashes with related field 'User.itemlocator_company_related1'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'last_updated_by'.
```

I'm on Django 1.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your related_name for created_by and last_updated_by are the same and should not be.

for what I can see your class Meta is ok, just change the related_name :)

Comment: wow, I can't believe I missed that.  I was so sure it was an issue with using an abstract model, that I overlooked the obvious.  Thanks.